# How can process a date that is in d/m/yyyy?

Tags: c#, date-format

I have to process dates . If the format i specify is mm/dd/yyyy and the date is like 7/5/2013, it is throwing a format exception. Does the date has to be like 07/05/2013? If yes how can i change the date from 7/5/2013 to 07/05/2013 programatically ? and the date format is not specific. I can have dates in mm-dd-yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd and the dates can come like 7-5-2013.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx) method, and specify the format as `M/d/yyyy` (or `d/M/yyyy`, depending on what exactly you need):

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "M/d/yyyy");
```

There is also an overload which can handle multiple date formats:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, 
    new[] { "M/d/yyyy", "M-d-yyyy" }, 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None);
```

This might still throw a `FormatException` if the input is in not in one of the allowed formats. To handle this a bit more safely, take a look at the [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) method:

```
DateTime date;
var success = DateTime.TryParseExact(
    input, 
    new[] { "M/d/yyyy", "M-d-yyyy" }, 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, 
    out date);
```

Don't forget to specify the correct format / and invariant culture when you're converting the date back to a string:

```
var output = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Or indeed, `d/m/yyyy`, since that is what the question states

Comment: @MarcGravell That's what the title says, but the question itself is ambiguous.

Comment: can it accept a date like 12/11/2013 or a date like 9/15/2013?

Comment: Note that these should use `M`, not `m` - `m` is for minutes.

Comment: do i need to use a namespace for DateTimeStyles?

Comment: @user2668901 add `using System.Globalization;`. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I used : 
string date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(UseDate, new[] { "M/d/yyyy", "MM/d/yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy" }, null, DateTimeStyles.None).ToString();
 as my date actually is in MM/dd/yyyy but it can be in M/d/yyyy
but still throws a format exception . Am sorry to confuse you.

Comment: @user2668901 Looks to me like you also need to specify the format with a `-` separator as well as the ones with the `/` separator.

Comment: Yes now when i try to parse a date like 12/01/2013 with the above code it throws an exception

Comment: @user2668901 What, even when you specify all the formats with `/` AND all the formats with `-`? If so, can you update your code in the OP to demonstrate the problem with some compilable code?

Comment: You should add the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, otherwise the `/` will be localized I think

Comment: UseDate = "12/01/2013";
                    string date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(UseDate, new[] { "M/d/yyyy", "MM/d/yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy","dd/MM/yyyy" }, null, DateTimeStyles.None).ToString();
                      

this is what am trying to do it throws an error

Comment: @xanatos Of course. I had forgotten about that. OP *could* try escaping the `/` but that seems to be a simpler solution.

Comment: @user2668901 *xanatos*'s suggestion should work. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Could you please be more elaborate about including the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture . Where do i include that .

Comment: @user2668901 See the code my updated answer. It should come after the formats array.