# RegEx to match M/YYYY, MM/YYYY , M/YY or MM/YY format but not MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: c#, regex, date

Okay, I have fought with this long enough.  I have a regex

```
^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]|\d)\/(20\d{2}|19\d{2}|0(?!0)\d|[1-9]\d)
```

which will match 8/15, 08/15, 8/2015, 08/2015 all of which I need.  So far so good.  But what I don't need is for it to match 08/01/2015 but I get a partial match on 08/01.  How do I ignore 08/01/2015?

Comment: If you're using `C#`, why use regex when you can use the `DateTime` library? You're almost certain to find an answer in regex that will fail for a specific case. What about leap years? Or months with less than 30 days? The list goes on.

Comment: Maybe a [negative look ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will help. Try `(?!/)` at the end of your pattern.

Comment: @Rob  I am searching through hundreds documents with tens of thousands of words and tens of dates in them trying to find the dates.  This is a multi pass process, in the first pass I am just trying to find dates that do not fit the pattern xx/dd/yyyy or xx/dd/yy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex if your string is starting with digit.

```
^\d{1,2}\/(?:\d{2}|\d{4})(?!\/)
```

Answer (score 5):

`DateTime.ParseExact` is a much more readable and maintainable way to address your issue: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx

If I were your colleague, I would hate reading this ugly regex when the same concept can be so elegantly expressed with a designated library class.

Actually an even better idea is `TryParseExact`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx

As you can see, there's an overload that accepts multiple formats, which is exactly your case and you can pass `["M/yyyy", "MM/yyyy, "M/yy", "MM/yy"]`.

Here's a code example for a case very similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18247797/326370

Comment: Hm. Nice. But how do you parse a string like `08/01/2015 is a sample date` by using `TryParseExact`? Or a correct sample `08/2015 is a sample date`.

Comment: If I were trying to validate one or to dates this may be an approach.  I am searching through documents with tens of thousands of words and tens of dates in them trying to find the dates.  So I doubt the effectiveness of using a method that will not find a hit in 99% of the cases.  If I were your colleague I would assume you are smart enough to ask a question and not try to convince you that you are solving the wrong problem.

Comment: Touché :-)
People do sometimes try to solve the wrong problem, but I was wrong to assume that about you.